# Customizable Web Based Editor?

Tags: javascript, editor, customization

I'm looking for a web-based wysiwyg style editor, that is straight-forward to customize. I want to limit the options to just a few choices...

undo/redo, uppercase, lowercase, spellcheck, find, clipboard options, and only a few choices of style that I would like to be able to name and possibly write the code for. It will basically grab the text around the cursor (without having to necessarily select) and format it according to parts of a video script.

What is a good editor to do this with (easy points to customize), and is there any examples of possibly similar customizations being done like this already out there?

Comment: something like tinyMCE editor?

Comment: I'm aware of javascript web-based editors, I'm looking for one that is easy to extend

Answer (score 0):

Try http://ckeditor.com/demo
It used to be called fckeditor earlier.

Comment: Is there any examples of adding styling that is performed programmatically?